# Heroku webhook with Discord.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get a notification from heroku to a discord webhook.
The way I'm trying is to create a Heroku webhook and putting my app's url as the Payload URL (let's say it is https://app.heroku.com). But the website always has an error and heroku always logs a crash. Heroku says that it automatically routes the https requests to the dyno (`node .` in this case). How do I handle the HTTP POST request from my code? I have no idea about this.

Comment: Could you provide your code and the error you're receiving?

Comment: I'm not receiving any error, it's just that I don't know anything about handling POST requests

Comment: You would need to set up a server (using [express.js](https://expressjs.com) for example) to handle the post requests.